# Exception in parsing JSON in android

Tags: android, json, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

My code is :

```
     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
        OPERATION_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

    try

    {

        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Object response = envelope.getResponse();
        System.out.println("response : " + response.toString());
}
```

The response shown in the console :

```
03-21 14:23:30.532: INFO/System.out(4311): response : Map{item=anyType{key=2; value=Apple; }; item=anyType{key=1; value=Orange; }; }
```

How can i parse this JSOn Object.. I have tried  with

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject( response.toString());
```

But an exception is thrown :

```
03-21 14:17:03.423: WARN/System.err(4210): org.json.JSONException: Value Map of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

**My web service method :**

```
 public JSONObject getContactNames(){
        JSONObject names = load();
        System.out.println("names "+names);
        return names;

    }
```

WSDL :

```
<wsdl:types>
  <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://service.asset.ey.com" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <element name="getContactNames">
    <complexType/>
   </element>
   <element name="getContactNamesResponse">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="getContactNamesReturn" type="xsd:anyType"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
  </schema>
 </wsdl:types>

   <wsdl:message name="getContactNamesRequest">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:getContactNames" name="parameters"/>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="getContactNamesResponse">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:getContactNamesResponse" name="parameters"/>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:portType name="ContactDetails">

      <wsdl:operation name="getContactNames">

         <wsdl:input message="impl:getContactNamesRequest" name="getContactNamesRequest"/>

         <wsdl:output message="impl:getContactNamesResponse" name="getContactNamesResponse"/>

      </wsdl:operation>

   </wsdl:portType>

   <wsdl:binding name="ContactDetailsSoapBinding" type="impl:ContactDetails">

      <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

      <wsdl:operation name="getContactNames">

         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

         <wsdl:input name="getContactNamesRequest">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output name="getContactNamesResponse">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

   </wsdl:binding>
```

Please Help in parsing the response:

Comment: The response you got is not JSON-formatted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Map{item=anyType{key=2; value=Apple; }; item=anyType{key=1; value=Orange; }; }

Is not valid json object. for more info how to construct json objects check the docs http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: this is the information retrieved from a web service call.. I have given my wsdl and webservice method

Comment: If you're using some service to get the response check your service but the response is definitely to json. You can use this online checker to verify if it's json http://www.jsonlint.com/. Try to locate the problem in the service.

Comment: I got the response as {"2":"Apple","1":"Orange"}   and it is valid.. How can i parse that

Comment: What do you mean by parse.JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject({"2":"Apple","1":"Orange"});jobj.getString("2") // return the value of key 2 which is Apple jobj.getString("1") // return Orange